# Is there anyway to rename the "Source" button to something like "HTML"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

Is there anyway to rename the "Source" button to something like "HTML", I ask this as users are confused at how to add html code using the editor?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, inside of the "lang" folder you will see all of the various language files.

For my case, and probably yours, You will want to edit the file "en.js". The file is "compressed" to some degree so it may be difficult to read, but it's still not too difficult to change one string. If you do plan on changing multiple strings you will most likely want to use a service to format Javascript.

Search for the following segment of code. It was one of the very last lines in the file.

```
"sourcearea":{"toolbar":"Source"}
```

change it to

```
"sourcearea":{"toolbar":"HTML"}
```

---

**Avoid This Method Unless Required**

And as for a very unsuggested method, since you can't modify the language files for some reason, you can modify the ckeditor.js file and force a specific label.

Inside of "ckeditor.js" change the line below

```
a.ui.addButton("Source",{label:a.lang.sourcearea.toolbar,command:"source",toolbar:"mode,10"});
```

to the follow code

```
a.ui.addButton("Source",{label:"HTML",command:"source",toolbar:"mode,10"});
```

The only thing modified is the "label" value in the above line. We remove the reference to the a.language.sourcearea.toolbar and insert a string in it's place instead.

Comment: Thanks @David.. for the suggestion. But I can't edit the en.js as my application is on ruby on rails .  The library files are in gems.

Comment: I've never used CKEditor, so I am unsure how it works with Ruby. But it appears that you can't change it using only the config.js file. I don't understand why you aren't able to modify the en.js file if you can modify the config.js

Comment: Thanks @David, It works with me the first option also.. Need to manage with the gem.. Thanks for saving a lot of time.